# php multiple mysql commands in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible build an array of SQL commands to query the DB?  What I have is three tables, each have columns with amounts due.  Would like to select anything that is due and display on screen so it can be invoiced (preferably in a table) and each row with it's respective customers dues.

I can select everything that is due using UNION ALL between the three tables, however I cant figure out how to list them by ID in the table row.

Below is what I have so far. At this pace I'll have to run each query separately and list them in three separate lists.  Suggestions?

```
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th> Cost 1</th>
            <th> Cost 2</th>
            <th> Cost 3</th>
        </tr>

      <?php 
    $list1 = "SELECT ID, Cost FROM Table1 WHERE Invoiced IS NULL;";
    //$list2 = "SELECT ID, Price2 FROM Table2 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate';";
    //$list3 = "SELECT ID, Price3 FROM Table3 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'";

    $result = mysql_query($list1, $link) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    for ($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) {
            $invoice[$i][mysql_fieldname($result,$j)] = mysql_result($result,$i,mysql_field_name($result,$j));
            }
        }

    //eventually the order it should be listed on screen
    for($i=0; $i<count($invoice); $i++) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$invoice[$i]["ID"]."</td>
        <td>".$invoice[$i]["Cost"]."</td>
        <td>".$invoice[$i]["Price2"]."</td>
        <td>".$invoice[$i]["Price3"]."</td></tr>";
    }

      ?>
      </table>
```

**Edit after comment:**

Query being passed and returning syntax error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'all LEFT JOIN table1 ON all.ID = table1.ID LEFT JOIN t' at line 7`:

```
    $query = "
    SELECT all.ID, table1.Cost1, table2.Price2, tabl3.Price3
    FROM 
        (SELECT ID, Cost1 FROM table1 WHERE Invoiced IS NULL
            UNION
        SELECT ID, Price2 FROM table2 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'
            UNION
        SELECT ID, Price3 FROM table3 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate') AS all
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON all.ID = table1.ID
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON all.ID = table2.ID
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON all.ID = table3.ID
    ";
```

Comment: so many suggestions come to mind. 1: Don't use mysql_* commands as they are deprecated. 2: Why are these items which look almost exactly the same in different tables. 3: Your use of rows and fields isn't needed, and is just an extremely large overhead.

Comment: @Frederico I renamed the tables and their columns to not confuse here, they all serve different functions and should not be in the same table.

Comment: @gSaenz Make yours look like mine. 2 things different about it: 1) The source of your syntax error is the fact that you used all as the derived table alias where I used allID. ALL is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and must be quoted with backtickts. 2) You don't need the costs or WHERE clauses in the UNION query, only the IDs. If you include the costs too, you'll get duplicates. – Michael Berkowski just now edit

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Perfect. Question, I was throwing the WHERE clauses to 1) make my search faster, isn't the way it is now (without WHERE) going to select everything?  Also, does this method account for duplicates?  See, each table is a different product and each customer can have more than one of each product.  2) Thus wanting to get only the ones that are due soon.  For example: ID 1 has two products from table2, one expires next month and the other expires next year.  This is why I was using `BETWEEN` (and `Invoiced IS NULL`) to get only the one that are due next month (and not billed yet)

Comment: @gSaenz Oops,  my mistake - while I meant for you to omit the WHERE from the UNION subquery, it still needs to be on the main query. I didn't intend to leave it out when I hastily typed that - added it below.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah! I just had it in the wrong section.  Appreciate explaining and not just giving a solution, Thank you!

Comment: @gSaenz An _answer_ should always have both a solution and a strong explanation.  Don't be afraid to ask for explanations when you ask a question but only get code sample solutions!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wouldn't the `WHERE` clause restrict results for which all conditions are met?  The way I read this; return everything where there is a customerID in each table meeting each criteria.  When what I'm shooting for is any and all results from each table meeting criteria, but grouped results.  Also, just noticed that need to account for the case where there might be more than one product to invoice in one table meeting the where clause, thus needing added.  What about creating a temporary table to join against? This is turning out to be more complex than I had intended it to be.

Comment: Ran out of space, but basically Would like to select anything that is due and display on screen so it can be invoiced (preferably in a table) and each row with it's respective customers dues.  Anything due is anything not invoiced and anything expiring withing a date range.

Comment: Yes it will limit over all conditions.  To split them, you must use subqueries joined together, as I added below.  Failing this, you need to ask a new question which actually explains your table structure and relations.  This started out as a PHP question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the table header you have created above which places the three Cost columns in a single row by `ID`, you seem to imply that you want to to `JOIN` the three tables together on their `ID`. I am using a `LEFT JOIN` here, to be sure that all rows from `Table1` are present, even if there is no corresponding row in either of the other two tables.

```
SELECT
  Table1.ID,
  Table1.Cost as Cost1,
  Table2.Price2 AS Cost2,
  Table3.Price3 AS Cost3
FROM
  Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID
WHERE 
  Table1.Invoiced IS NULL
  AND Table2.Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'
  AND Table3.Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'
```

#### Update after comments:

In the case that `Table2` may have an `ID` not held in `Table1` or `Table3`, for example (where `Table1.ID` can't be considered authoritative), you can get the total set of `DISTINCT ID` from all 3 tables via a `UNION` and use that to join against:

```
SELECT
  allID.ID,
  Table1.Cost1,
  Table2.Price2 AS Cost2,
  Table2.Price3 AS Cost3
FROM
  /* Subquery gets a distinct set of IDs from all tables via UNION 
     so the outer query has a complete list to join against the other tables */
  (
    SELECT ID FROM Table1
    UNION SELECT ID FROM Table2
    UNION SELECT ID FROM Table3
  ) allID
  LEFT JOIN Table1 ON allID.ID = Table1.ID
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON allID.ID = Table2.ID
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON allID.ID = Table3.ID
/* Sorry, forgot the WHERE clause here */
WHERE
  Table1.Invoiced IS NULL
  AND Table2.Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'
  AND Table3.Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate'
```

Note that the existence of three tables with nearly identical column structures in a one-to-one relationship probably implies a design problem. You might consider combining these into a single table.

#### A further note about the PHP:

In PHP, we almost never use an incremental `for` loop for iteration as you would in C/C++. Instead, we typically make use of a `foreach` or when fetching rows from a query, a `while` loop.

```
// Fetch in a while loop
$invoice = array();
// $result is your query resource as you already have it...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // Accumulate rows into $invoice array
  $invoice[] = $row;
}
// Then loop over the array:
foreach ($invoice as $inv) {
  echo "<tr>
    <td>{$inv['ID']}</td>
    <td>{$inv['Cost1']}</td>
    <td>{$inv['Cost2']}</td>
    <td>{$inv['Cost3']}</td>
  </tr>"; 
}
```

#### Final update:

Yes, the `WHERE` clause will restrict for all conditions met. If you need to limit them individually, you must do so in subqueries which are then joined together, using the same `UNION` subquery to get the distinct set of `ID`

```
SELECT
  allID.ID,
  T1.Cost1,
  T2.Price2 AS Cost2,
  T3.Price3 AS Cost3
FROM
  (
    SELECT ID FROM Table1
    UNION SELECT ID FROM Table2
    UNION SELECT ID FROM Table3
  ) allID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Cost AS Cost1 FROM Table1 WHERE Invoiced IS NULL) T1 ON allID.ID = T1.ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Price2 AS Cost2 FROM Table2 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate') T2 ON allID.ID = T2.ID
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Price3 AS Cost3 FROM Table3 WHERE Expiration BETWEEN '$curDate' AND '$maxDate') T3 ON allID.ID = T3.ID
```

Comment: I renamed the tables and their columns to not confuse here, they all serve different functions and should not be in the same table.  Regarding the LEFT JOIN, I thought about that also.  However there may be items in table2 to invoice while that customer (from table2) may not have anything to invoice on table1 or 3.  These three tables have no relationship to each other.  I will change to while loop, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @gSaenz Have a look at the new query added above, which uses a subquery that builds a distinct list of all possible `ID`, no matter which tables they do or do not exist in.

Comment: logic seems to be there, however it returns a syntax error.  Have updated my query above.  Thank you

Comment: @gSaenz Make yours look like mine.  2 things different about it: 1) The source of your syntax error is the fact that you used `all` as the derived table alias where I used `allID`.  `ALL` is a MySQL  reserved keyword and must be quoted with backtickts.  2) You don't need the costs or WHERE clauses in the UNION query, only the IDs. If you include the costs too, you'll get duplicates.